# I'm getting a --run-time error while using locust distributed load (local)

Tags: python, load-testing, distributed, locust

Hello I was following this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/FDYD2inSSPY?list=PLJ9A48W0kpRKMCzJARCObgJs3SinOewp5

I recreated his steps:
First I created two config files:

*master.conf*

```
[master conf]
master = true
expect-workers = 1

[runtime settings]
host = https://petstore.octoperf.com
users = 3
spawn-rate = 2
locustfile = petstore.py
run-time = 30s
headless = true
only-summary = true
```

*worker.conf*

```
[worker conf]
worker = true
locustfile = petstore.py
```

I then proceed to run this two instructions in different terminals:
`locust --config=master.conf` and `locust --config=worker.conf`

The first one didn't create a problem, the second one showed this error:

`*/ERROR/locust.main: --run-time should be specified on the master node, and not on worker nodes`

But as you can see the --run-time configuration is in the master.conf not in the worker.conf

I search in the locust documentation but I didn't find anything on this particular topic.

Comment: Huh. Weird. And you wouldnt happen to have any values set using environment variables or anything?

Comment: I thought the same thing and I checked the envs but I didn't find anything related to locust, I tried the same setting on a different computer and it worked